# How to highlight/detect the table header with specfic text value jquery

Tags: jquery

I have table which is have 8 column header, on click on another button event i want to detect or highlight the table header which is having text value of "s.no"... any soln?

Comment: I'm voting to place your question on hold, as 'unclear what you're asking,' because of the vague nature of the question (lack of relevant code, no demonstrated attempts at a solution, poor definition of the problem itself). Also, and this is entirely personal, the use of 'any soln?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#gethead").click(function() {
    $("#table1").find('th').each(function(){  
    if($(this).text()=="Sno")
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
});
```

```css
.highlight{
    background-color:green;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <th>Sno</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" id="sec">asdasd</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" id="gethead">outside</a>
```

Comment: Its not working if my click event, i.e the button out side of table?

Comment: @Krish Editted please check